# Nuance of Noun-verb　(を）入る/入れる

Tags: grammar, transitivity

> ええ～、なかなかいらっしゃらないからと、近隣の署に片っ端から**連絡を入れた**そうですよ

eh, you didn't show up, so it seemed like  (she) contacted every police station in the area

> おたくらちょっとそれ軽く**いじめ入ってる**よ！？　自覚あります！？

you Otakus, you're sorta (trivially?) bullying me, you realize that?

What is the different between these usages and just simply the verb itself? (連絡する・いじめる) ?

on a side note, what is the best way to read 軽く here? The speaker is honestly pretty damn upset in this situation.

thanks

Comment: This おたく is probably a simple polite second-person pronoun. "You guys" rather than "You nerds".

Comment: hm i guess that was a bit confusing since the these bullies in quesiton are in fact otakus/nerds as well haha

Comment: Even if that's the case, おたくら almost always means "you guys", "you folks", etc. おたく meaning nerd is not a person pronoun in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are assuming the examples you gave for `[入]{い}れる` and `[入]{はい}る` are functionally the same, but they aren't.

In regard to your first sentence: both `入れる` and `入る` are used with `連絡` to describe the action of contacting someone, or contact having come in, respectively. See [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%A1%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B&ref=sa), [here](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9101007.html) and [here](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%A1%E3%81%8C%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B). You can take this `連絡を入れた` largely the same way you would take `連絡した`.

In regard to the second sentence, and how `いじめが入っている` is different from simply `いじめる`, I think it becomes clearer if we think about grammatical structure here.

> 人をいじめる

Is simply to "bully someone", where the person is the direct object of bullying, and that's all that's happening. Conversely

> いじめが入っている

Is talking about "bullying being in" something else, such as someone's actions, words, or just about anything. You could say `いじめの入っている行動` to describe action that included or amounted to bullying, but might not primarily or explicitly be bullying.

In short, the speaker in your second sentence is telling whoever he's talking to that whatever `それ` is includes or amounts to bullying, whether they intended for it to or not.

Lastly, in regards to the usage of `軽く` - it can really just mean "lightly" or more colloquially "a little bit", which I don't think would be a strange here as you think. That said, the word can also carry nuances like the English phrase "to take lightly", in the sense that these people may not be giving much thought to the bullying or taking it very seriously.

Edit: As Naruto points out, this `おたくら` is likely not referring to actual otaku, but is being used as a pronoun.